# Error: webpack-dev-server with ReactJS and Django

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I try to create a full stack environment with Django + ReactJS. Here, I use Webpack bundler and I'm getting this error while I try to run my webpack-server from a `virtualenv`. I'm very new to the application development and this is my first attempt, So can anyone help me out?

```
PS C:\Users\NikhileshSubramanian\Desktop\eduWebApp\env\frontend> npm run dev
```

> frontend@0.1.0 dev C:\Users\NikhileshSubramanian\Desktop\eduWebApp\env\frontend
>   webpack-dev-server
>   module.js:549
>       throw err;
>       ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NikhileshSubramanian\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\compiler.js:9:28)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NikhileshSubramanian\AppData\Roaming\npm- 
cache\_logs\2018-09-29T07_48_56_942Z-debug.log
```

Scripts inside my package.json

```
"scripts": {
       "start": "react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject",
       "buildwebpack": "webpack",
       "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
          "webpack": "^4.20.2",
          "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
          "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
    }
```

Project Working Directory
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1v0p.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack is inbuilt in React modules when we create a project via `create-react-app`. That's how Facebook has developed to reduce concentrating about environment setup and look into building the application. So, there's an easy way to create our project avoiding Webpack initiation.

Refer:
https://www.techiediaries.com/react-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you are using windows system.So maybe you need configure environment variables for this "webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin" module. Then it can find the module.

Comment: Thanks. But, this time" Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'" even after adding 'my/project/frontend/node_modules/webpack' to my path.

Comment: Maybe you should specify the exact path for the plugin "NodeTemplatePlugin".